# Two divs next to each other which add up to 100% width - one appears below the other?

Tags: html, css, css-float, word-wrap

I have a container div which is centred at 50% of the page width. This has 10px padding and position relative. I then have a div inside this which is set to width 80%, float left and is a different colour, and also has padding of 10px. There is another div set to float right which has width 20%. Neither of the nested divs have a border or margin. However the right one appears below the other one **only** up to a particular screen size.

My html / css is as follows:

```
<html>
    <head>
        CSS file included here
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="page-container">
            <div class="right-col"></div>
            <div class="left-col"></div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>


.page-container {
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.left-col {
    width: 80%;
    float: left;
}

.right-col {
    width: 20%;
    float: right;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

This has been bugging me for ages so I would appreciate any help anyone can give me. Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Richard

Comment: It might possibly be the rounding error. I would never use up all 100% of width, you may try changing .left-col to width:79% instead.

Comment: I tried this about an hour ago - think I ended up taking the left column down to 77% and the other down to 17%... it sounds like there is a margin in there somewhere - but I tried explicitly setting margin to 0 to no avail. Using the 77 / 17% thing also only works down to a particular size, under which I get the same result.

Comment: If you inspect it with Firebug, you'll be able to see the box model for each div, including any margin or padding.  It should be more clear what's happening at that point.

Comment: I'll try that tomorrow... well, today at about 12 when I've had a few hours kip. Unfortunately my computer doesn't like Firefox - sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't - so I tend to avoid it and stick to Chrome / Opera. They tend to give me a good idea of how Firefox will display things. Will let you know how it goes.

Comment: I prefer Chrome for general browsing too. The other browsers' dev tools still don't match Firebug for web development though.

Comment: I think Michael has the answer - add a div inside each column to apply the padding. I thought padding was included in the width - think it must be IE that does that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example doesn't contain any padding and looks the same at any screen size. If you add padding to the left div it gets added to the total width so it gets a width of 80% + 20px. If your content in  the left div needs some padding add another div inside it with a 10px margin.

```
   <div class="page-container">
        <div class="right-col"></div>
        <div class="left-col">
            <div class="left-col-inner"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
```

css

```
.left-col-inner{
margin:10px;
}
```

Comment: I think this might be it. Thanks. Will let you know the result when I next work on this.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying nearly 100% width, eg 19.99% or 79.99%.

Comment: That was suggested by xandy. It didnt work (read my reply to his comment for how it didnt work).

Answer (score 0):

Michael has it.

If you want to avoid inserting another div inside div.left-col you could give all of its immediate children margin or padding.

```
div.left-col > * {
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```